# NULL POINTER EXCEPTION for arrayadapter in listview. ANDROID

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, nullpointerexception

I have a main view(listview) and a second main view(edittext). I pass data from second main view backwards to first main view using startActivityforResult(). I have tested it out and I recieve the string back with no problem. However there are some problems displaying it on listview. My listview has two xml files one for the listview layout and one for the textview row. I have no idea why I am getting a nullpointer exception.

```
03-14 22:50:33.429    9268-9268/com.example.anusha.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.anusha.app, PID: 9268
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2780)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2308)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2030)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1267)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6640)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my first main view with my listview. I'm pretty sure the problem is with the arrayadapter. Don't know what it is though.

```
 ArrayList<String> array= new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_address_list);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_address_list,R.id.rowTextView, array);
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);



}
private void Add() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddressList.this, SilentGeofence.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            array.add(result);


        }
    }
    }
```

Here is my second main

```
   Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            String ag = txt1.getText().toString().trim();
                txt1.setText("");
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result",ag);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                finish();
```

Comment: array is not populated with items. Where do you call Add()??

Comment: your problem is `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_address_list,R.id.rowTextView, array);`. read documentation to how to populate `arrayAdapter`

Comment: i call Add()  onOptionsItemSelected() in menu.It's one of my bar button items. @Raghunandan

Comment: I am using public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) @shayanpourvatan

Comment: The array is getting items from the second main and getting updated in onActivityResult() right?

Comment: see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter

Comment: R.layout.activity_address_list does this have your listview or textview

Comment: @anu - Please visit [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190). Why do new members discard the help from more experienced folks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)

Added in API level 1
Constructor

Parameters
context The current context.
resource    The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
textViewResourceId  The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated
objects The objects to represent in the ListView.

So you should use layout of the textview not the listview layout see here 
[see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]))

```
    new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.layout_name_of_the_xml_containing_textview,R.id.rowTextView, array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise your list in `onCreate()`, Just after the `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

And your `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter` should be a field not a local variable because, after you do `array.add(result)` you must also call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in order to refresh and populate the results in the listview

Comment: didn't work. I made a Array Adapter a field variable and put adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after array.add(result) and the app still crashed @Ishan Khanna

Comment: it crashes saying: System services not available to Activities before onCreate() @ishan-khanna